# How do I get the Item Name using an XSL rendering?

Tags: xslt, sitecore

I have an xsl rendering that looks through a list of items.

I want to put the Item Name (as in what you see under Quick Info for an item) into a variable.

To do this for a field that is entered in the Builder tab you would do this:

`<xsl:variable name="variablename" select="sc.fld('Field Name',.)" />`

but I'm not sure what the name for the Item Name is. Is it `<xsl:variable name="variablename" select="sc.fld('Item Name',.)" />` or `<xsl:variable name="variablename" select="sc.fld('ItemName',.)" />` or is it not possible to get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `@name` property.

Like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="itemname" select="./@name" />
```

By the way, if you want the Display Name instead you need to use:

```
<xsl:variable name="displayname" select="sc:fld('__display name',.) />
```